# Ctags is stubbornly refusing to print line numbers

Tags: editor, ctags

I am experimenting with Ctags in my cmd terminal. Perhaps I should first give some background information about my system:

- Windows 10, 64-bit
- Installed Ctags from this source: https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags-win32/releases
- Added Ctags to my PATH variable

First I navigate to my C/C++ source folder with the cmd terminal. Then I issue the following command:

```
ctags -R --output-format=json -f tag.tg
```

I get a tag file in the current directory as expected. The tag-file refers to each tag using a `pattern`. That's great, but I want to have line-numers instead. So I remove the tag file first, and rebuild it with the following command:

```
ctags -R --output-format=json --excmd=number -f tag.tg
```

But nothing changes. I still got a `pattern` field where I want to have a `line-number` field (not sure how that field would be named exactly, but you get the point).

What did I do wrong?

---

I tried the following approach:

```
ctags -R --output-format=json --fields="n" -f tag.tg
```

This gives me indeed the `"line"` field. But the `"typeref"`, `"kind"`, `"scope"` and `"scopeKind"` fields are gone.

The following approach keeps all those fields:

```
ctags -R --output-format=json --fields="+n" -f tag.tg
```

Thank you Stargateur for your answer :-)

Comment: Possibly a side effect of the json output format? What happens if you remove that? Or put it after the --excmd option?

Comment: If I remember correctly, windows 10 already has a `ctags` function, available from the command line.

Comment: It seems you have the source code available.  Why not just examine the source code to determine what you need to do.

Comment: Hey @ChrisTurner , you're right! It is a side-effect when I choose the json-format. Putting the json-format option after `--excmd=number` doesn't help. I only get the line numbers when I remove the json-format option alltogether.

Comment: Hi @user3629249, that would be great. But I am not familiar with the source code of Ctags. It would take me humungous amount of study-time to  get deeper insight in that source-code.

Comment: I found on http://docs.ctags.io/en/latest/output-json.html that the JSON format is still being developed so I suspect unless you take matters into your own hands it might be a while before it does what you want

Comment: You didn't ask for anything else than line number in your original question, please if you want an accurate answer do an accurate question ! Provide exemple of desired output, provide exemple of actual output, etc.

Comment: Hi @Stargateur, I'm sorry I have offended you - it was certainly not my intention. Please know that I do appreciate your answer a lot! (By adding a `+` sign, I can also keep the other fields).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.ctags.io/en/latest/output-json.html) you need to ask specific field with `--fields` option:

```
 ctags -R --output-format=json --fields="n" -f tag.tg
```

Works for me.

You can see full list of option with:

```
ctags --list-fields
```

Comment: Hi @Stargateur. Your approach works .. but it has some complications (see my updated question).

Comment: Thank you @Stargateur. Problem is solved now. I appreciate your help :-)